# How to display only SEI VUI Frames using ffmpeg or ffprobe tools or any other standard tool?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, ffprobe

I tried ffprobe -show_format -show_streams -show_frames input_video  , but this is not displaying exact sei vui  frames information like their frame number length etc. what command can be used for the same

Comment: [FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=0
pkt_pts=N/A
pkt_pts_time=N/A
pkt_dts=N/A
pkt_dts_time=N/A
best_effort_timestamp=N/A
best_effort_timestamp_time=N/A
pkt_duration=10000
pkt_duration_time=0.008333
pkt_pos=467928
pkt_size=132010
width=1280
height=720
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=1
top_field_first=1
repeat_pict=0
[/FRAME]

Comment: I am getting this information after using ffprobe but not the NAL unit type information

Comment: Don't believe ff* tools do this. You'll need a bitstream parser/analyzer for H.264/5.